# javascript - call a function from another function

Tags: javascript, function

For example, in my html i have:

```
<script>
   var mouvement = 1;
   makemouvement(mouvement);
</script>

<script>
  function test(){
    function subtest1(){
      //...
    };
    function subtest2(){
      //...
    };
    function makemouvement(mouvement){
      alert(mouvement);
      //...
    };
  }
</script>
```

how can I call the "makemouvement" function (which is inside test function) from my first script plz?

Comment: 1. `makemouvement` doesn't exist until you run `test`. 2. There is no way to access it

Comment: define `makemouvement` in a global scope or attach it to an object

Answer (score 1):

You can move `makemouvement` to the global scope. Try this:

```
<script>
   var mouvement = 1;
   test()
   makemouvement(mouvement);
</script>

<script>
  function test(){
    function subtest1(){
      //...
    };
    function subtest2(){
      //...
    };
    window.makemouvement(mouvement){
      alert(mouvement);
      //...
    };
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Only if you call `test` first

Comment: @AlexBorodin Thanks a lot, I didn't call the fucntion test first.